# Custom cell label wont wordwrap

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview, uilabel

I created a custom `UITableViewCell` which is the same as the *Left Detail* cell but instead of a detailLabel it has a `UITextField` I matched ALL properties between the label in my custom cell and the label for the *Left Detail* cell however it will not word wrap. It will display the first word then instead of wrapping it just cuts the rest off without truncating. I am guessing that it is word wrapping but instead of making the label height bigger it is keep it the same as a one line label.

I have

- label lines set to 0
- line breaks set to word wrap
- View autosizing set to the same as *Left Detail*

I did this in IB so I was able to match every setting. Anyone know how to make the custom labels for cells auto wrap?

EDIT:

To be clear I am wanting the custom label to word wrap not the textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making the label the size of the cell instead of being static. This allowed it to wrap.

Answer (score 1):

`UITextField` is one line only. Perhaps you mean `UITextView`? Review the Apple documentation on both classes. I have used a `UITextView` with multiline successfully in a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Sorry if you were confused by I stated above the **label** is not wrapping.